# std::unique with class objects

Tags: c++, stl, deque

There is a deque with pointers to class objects :

```
deque<myClass*> mydeque;
```

Say we have 3 objects in the deque: `obj1, obj2, obj3`

Say based on some comparison logic `obj1` and `obj2` are considered same elements.

When we call `std::unique` on mydeque, it changes the deque into something like this:

```
obj1 obj3 obj3
```

This is because as per documentation of std::unique
    The removal is done by replacing the duplicate elements by the next element that is not a duplicate

`std::unique` returns an iterator to the last obj3.
If we want to free up the memory space occupied by obj2 (by calling delete), how do we achieve it?

Here we cannot call delete on the returned iterator because it will in-effect delete obj3.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers; use `std::shared_ptr<myClass>` and let sanity sort it out.

Comment: What happened to `obj3`?  Are you storing raw `new`ed pointers in the vector?

Comment: If you have `deque` of pointers then `std::unique` should handle objects with different addresses, so what's your problem here?

Comment: I have edited the question to explain it in a much better way

Comment: @WhozCraig or, even better: `std::unique_ptr`

Answer (score 1):

Use C++11 features. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers. That way when the pointer to `obj3` is overwritten its target will be deleted.

If this `mydeque` structure is not the owner of `myClass` objects then use `std::shared_ptr` instead.

A third option is to loop over the sorted deque and remove the duplicate values yourself. It has to already be sorted because `std::unique` only works on sorted intervals.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the documentation for [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) says:

> Removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten. **Relative order of the elements that remain is preserved and the *physical* size of the container is unchanged.**
>
> Iterators pointing to an element between the new *logical* end and the *physical* end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values.
>
> **A call to unique is typically followed by a call to a container's `erase` method**, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the *physical* size of the container to match its new *logical* size.

Note the 2 bold parts. The first one is important, it says that the relative order is preserved, i.e. after calling `std::unique`, your deque will still contain

```
obj1 obj2 obj3
```

They're order is not changed, why? Because the non-unique element is already at the end, `obj3`, and because the order is preserved, you can be sure that it will still be at the end.

The second bold part you already know, but now that you know that `std::unique` returns an iterator to one past the last valid element, you can call [`std::deque::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) to erase every non-unique element:

```
mydeque.erase(std::unique(mydeque.begin(), mydeque.end()), mydeque.end());
```

Also note that because you are storing pointers, the only way to have 2 same elements is to have 2 pointers pointing at the same address.

Comment: Correct. My bad, I gave the wrong example. I have corrected it

Comment: @bishwanathmandal `std::unique` doesn't replace anything, it just moves them to the end.

Comment: As per documentation of std::unique The removal is done by replacing the duplicate elements by the next element that is not a duplicate

Comment: **
The function cannot alter the properties of the object containing the range of elements (i.e., it cannot alter the size of an array or a container): The removal is done by replacing the duplicate elements by the next element that is not a duplicate, and signaling the new size of the shortened range by returning an iterator to the element that should be considered its new past-the-end element.**

Comment: @bishwanathmandal cplusplus is an outdated reference, and wrong most of the time, just like this time. You should be using cppreference instead, which states "removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten"

Comment: Even going by the reference : "removing is done by shifting the elements in the range in such a way that elements to be erased are overwritten.". What exactly overwritten signifies? Doesn't it mean that obj2 will be overwritten by obj3?

Comment: @bishwanathmandal No, just that obj3 will get shifted to the end, but because it is already at the end, nothing happens to the container *usually*, this can vary but `obj2` is not overwritten in any way, as it is the first unique element

Comment: The example that I had given earlier didn't depicted the scenario which I wanted to ask. I have updated the example.